# SQL: Can't get count(*) to work - why so?

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm trying to query a database for the count of entries that match the given ID, but I can't come up with a working solution.

There are two of each type of account that correspond to the userID of 1, for some reason the first method outputs "1" and the second "0". I can show the mainactivity and the database shchema if needed as well.

```
public int numberOfDebitAccounts(int userID){
    int numOf_accs = 0;
    String query = "select count(*) from debitAccount where userID = '" +userID+"'";
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        numOf_accs = cursor.getInt(0);
        System.out.println("Number of debit accs: " + numOf_accs);
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return numOf_accs;
}

public int numberOfCreditAccounts(int userID){
    int numOf_accs = 0;
    String query = "select count(accountID) from creditAccount where userID = '" +userID+"'";
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        numOf_accs = cursor.getInt(0);
        System.out.println("number of credit accounts: " + numOf_accs);
    }
    closeDatabase();
    return numOf_accs;
}
```

Comment: Can you check in database table of mbole. Is the userID has accountID or not if it is not then the query give 0

Comment: doing a basic sql query in sqlite3 with the same database and same statement gives the correct values

Comment: `... where userID = '" +userID+"'"` most likely, `userID` is a **NUMBER**, not a string. Try removing the string delimiters (`'`).

Comment: I know in SQL Server it doesn't matter if you use a String or int

Comment: Is it possible that you need to aggregrate it using `GROUP BY`? It's been awhile since I've used SQL. In other words `SELECT COUNT(UserID).... GROUP BY UserID`

Comment: @juice Well, here the query is explicitly telling the engine to compare a number with a string. Which simply **won't match**.

Comment: Those delimeters ' don't matter